# Can you catch the first Ultra Beast?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

During my first visit to the Aether Foundation conservatory I engaged in a battle with an Ultra Beast.  It fled before I could attempt to catch it.  I'm wondering if it were possible to have caught it during that first encounter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are forced to make that Ultra Beast flee by lowering its health below a certain threshold. You cannot catch Ultra Beasts until after the main story.

Comment: Could you put the name of the beast in a spoiler tag?  At this stage of the game it's name is not yet revealed.

Comment: @Colyn1337 how's that?

Comment: But you had the option to throw pokeballs at it, so if you got an ultra beast ball or whatever its called from a pokemon holding it in a trade, you could catch it early.

Comment: This is wrong. You cannot throw Pokeballs in overworld or wild encounters in Aether Paradise. This is explained with a jamming signal broadcast on the entire "island" in order to protect the Pokemon brought there for conservation purposes. You can throw them in Trainer battles, but the Trainer will of course block the Ball as always.